# Calling C dll from Fortran

Tags: dll, fortran

How to call C DLL from Fortran? I don't code in Fortran but I need to do some testing on it.

Let say in the test.dll have functions:

Open()

Close()

How can I tell Fortran to use the test.dll?

I mean like C# we may use

```
[DllImport("test.dll")]
static extern uint Open();
```

I could not find any example that can help me. I would also prefer if you could provide a compiler that you use.

**Update**

I use Plato compiler.

I tried to load test.dll using this method. However, it popped up error message saying Error 29, Call to missing routine: _LOADLIBRARY

Here is the code. I found it online. So not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

```
program test

integer                ::  p
pointer                :: q

p = loadlibrary    ("test.dll"C) ! the C at the end says -
                                    ! add a null byte as in C
q = getprocaddress (p, "Open"C)

end
```

[image: Error shown]

**EDIT**

Sorry. The DLL is using C and not C++

Comment: Have you tried to search for Fortran and C++ on this site? There are.many questions and answers about similar topics.

Comment: Mostly what I found was C++ calling Fortran dll. But another way around I could not find any.

Comment: It is almost the same as in C++ to Fortran. And very different from C#.

Comment: i'm not familiar with how to code them..the syntax is new to me

Comment: Are you able to call  a C++ DLL from C++? Are you able to call a Fortran DLL from Fortran? Do you know C++ at all? Do you know Fortran? We have to start somewhere.

Comment: Yes I able to call C++ DLL from C++. No, I don't have fortran DLL. Yes I know C++. I don't know Fortran.

Comment: If you don't know Fortran, how do you want to call the DLL? Do you have some code which should call it? Which code?

Comment: I need to run some tests between the dll and Fortran. Just to check if the DLL works with Fortran. I just need to do simple code to test the dll. But I don't know the code to call dll.

Comment: Please put your code as **text**, not a picture. Where do you find the `loadlibrary` and `getprocaddress` calls? Why did you try to use them? We need **details**. You don't normally need to do anything like that, you just do `call Open` and link the library (if Open is a Fortran subroutine). That's also what you do in C++. Are you sure you know how you call a symbol from a library in C++?

Comment: Ok sorry. My DLL is C language and not C++. Open is a function from the DLL. In my C++ code, we use LoadLibrary function and GetProcAddress function.

Comment: You don't need to do any LoadLibrary. Not Even in C and C++, you can just link against the .lib file.

Comment: we actually need to show that the dll is working with Fortran

Comment: @VladimirF can u help to show how to link against the .lib file?